# D3.js line chart continuous but want non continuous

Tags: d3.js, continuous

Hey guys I created a time series line chart using publicly available stock data.

Where I got to is the following:
[image: chart output]

Looks like what it is doing is connecting the first datapoint with the last datapoint which is why it is creating a line across the entire chart.

I looked online and read that to create a non continuous line chart I can add

```
.defined(function(d) { return d; })
```

I did but it didn't help.

My code:

```
        //Set dimensions and margins for the graph
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 70},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        //Create canvas
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        //Parse date
        var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

        //Set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        // Define the line
        var valueLine = d3.line()
            .defined(function(d) { return d; })
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

        //Import data from api
        d3.json("api_all.php", function(error, data) {
          if (error) throw error;
          data.forEach(e => {
            e.date = parseDate(e.date);
            e.value = +e.close;
            e.stockName = e.stock_name;
            e.stockSymbol = e.stock_symbol;
          });

          //Create nest variable
          var nest = d3.nest()
              .key(function(d){ return d.stockSymbol; })
              .entries(data);

          console.log(nest);
          //Scale the range of the data
          //x axis scale for entire dataset
          x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
          //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

          //Add the x axis
          var xaxis = svg.append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

          //Add x axis label
          svg.append("text")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2) + "," + (height + margin.top + 10) + ")")
              .attr("dy", "1em")
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text("Date")
              .attr("class", "x axis label");

          //Create dropdown
          var dropDown = d3.select("#dropDown")
          dropDown
            .append("select")
            .selectAll("option")
              .data(nest)
              .enter()
              .append("option")
              .attr("value", function(d){ return d.key; })
              .text(function(d){ return d.key; })

          // Function to create the initial graph
            var initialGraph = function(stock){

                // Filter the data to include only stock of interest
                var selectStock = nest.filter(function(d){
                        return d.key == stock;
                      })
              console.log(selectStock)

              //Unnest selectStock for y axis
              var unnested = function(data, children){
                        var out = [];
                  data.forEach(function(d, i){
                    console.log(i, d);
                    d_keys = Object.keys(d);
                    console.log(i, d_keys)
                    values = d[children];

                    values.forEach(function(v){
                        d_keys.forEach(function(k){
                        if (k != children) { v[k] = d[k]}
                      })
                      out.push(v);
                    })

                  })
                  return out;
                }
                var selectStockUnnested = unnested(selectStock, "values");


              //Scale y axis
                var selectStockGroups = svg.selectAll(".stockGroups")
                    .data(selectStock, function(d){
                      return d ? d.key : this.key;
                    })
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "stockGroups")
                    .each(function(d){
                        y.domain([0, d3.max(selectStockUnnested, function(d) { return d.value; })])
                        console.log(selectStockUnnested);
                    });

                var initialPath = selectStockGroups.selectAll(".line")
                    .data(selectStock)
                    .enter()
                    .append("path")

                initialPath
                    .attr("d", function(d){ return valueLine(d.values) })
                    .attr("class", "line")

                  //Add the y axis
              var yaxis = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
                      .ticks(5)
                      .tickSizeInner(0)
                      .tickPadding(6)
                      .tickSize(0, 0));

                  //Add y axis label
                  svg.append("text")
                        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                        .attr("y", 0 - 60)
                        .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
                        .attr("dy", "1em")
                        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .text("Price")
                        .attr("class", "y axis label");
            }

          // Create initial graph
            initialGraph("1301.T")

            // Update the data
            var updateGraph = function(stock){

                // Filter the data to include only stock of interest
                var selectStock = nest.filter(function(d){
                        return d.key == stock;
                      })
            console.log(selectStock);

            //Unnest selectStock for y axis
            var unnested = function(data, children){
                var out = [];
                data.forEach(function(d, i){
                  console.log(i, d);
                  d_keys = Object.keys(d);
                  console.log(i, d_keys)
                  values = d[children];

                  values.forEach(function(v){
                    d_keys.forEach(function(k){
                      if (k != children) { v[k] = d[k]}
                    })
                    out.push(v);
                  })

                })
                return out;
              }
              var selectStockUnnested = unnested(selectStock, "values");

                // Select all of the grouped elements and update the data
                var selectStockGroups = svg.selectAll(".stockGroups")
                    .data(selectStock)
                    .each(function(d){
                        y.domain([0, d3.max(selectStockUnnested, function(d) { return d.value; })])
                    });

                    // Select all the lines and transition to new positions
                    selectStockGroups.selectAll("path.line")
                       .data(selectStock)
                       .transition()
                          .duration(1000)
                          .attr("d", function(d){
                            return valueLine(d.values)
                          })

                // Update the Y-axis
                    d3.select(".y")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(1500)
                            .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
                              .ticks(5)
                              .tickSizeInner(0)
                              .tickPadding(6)
                              .tickSize(0, 0));
            }
          // Run update function when dropdown selection changes
          dropDown.on('change', function(){

            // Find which stock was selected from the dropdown
            var selectedStock = d3.select(this)
                    .select("select")
                    .property("value")
            console.log(selectedStock);
                // Run update function with the selected stock
                updateGraph(selectedStock)
          });
        });

        </script>
      </body>
```

Comment: In your CSS: `.line {fill: none;}`. Alternatively, set the `fill` in the D3 code itself.

Comment: `.line {fill: none;} ` makes the line disappear entirely

Comment: You have to set the stroke as well, set the fill to none and the stroke to any colour you want. That's the only problem with that path, nothing related to being *continuous*  or *non continuous*.